# Can I make table columns separate equally, similar to how flexbox works?

Tags: css, html-table, flexbox

Using `display: flex` on a wrapper element and `flex-grow: 1` on every child, if you think of the layout as a single row of a table, the "columns" are separated equally (the space between each, no matter what the content is, is the same).

When using a table, however, the layout doesn't work like that, so the space between the columns makes the table look unbalanced. [Here is an example to illustrate](https://jsfiddle.net/cambraca/Lr0uf7qn/3/):

[image: flexbox vs table "columns"]

**Is it possible for table columns to separate in a smarter way so that the separation between each is roughly similar?**

Comment: No, flexbox can't do that...but CSS-Grid probably can

Comment: `table-layout:fixed` would set each column the same width, `flex:1` would too for flex . can you add your working code and an image of your expected result . Grid would make rows and columns match.  If you clarify your question , we might advise you efficiently. `table-layout:fixed` : https://jsfiddle.net/uv82qs0p/ , `flex:1;` instead `flex-grow` *(to equally size your cells)* and `grid`  alternative *(no matter numbers of row and col, it matches)*: https://jsfiddle.net/uv82qs0p/1/